# Docker container linking via port forwarding?

Tags: docker

It seems that the preferred way to expose services to other Docker containers is container linking, which sets some environment variables that you then have to use in your application code to look up host names and port numbers:

```
 psql -h $PG_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p $PG_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT
```

Is there a reason this is not done via port forwarding in a way that is transparent to the application? So that in the same way that I can just run my web server inside the container on standard port 80 and have Docker figure out what actual port to use, I could just be doing

```
psql -h 0.0.0.0  # no -p necessary, we use the default port
```

The port forwarding would be set up when I start docker, just like with server ports.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible! It has actually be proposed by the CoreOS team; you can read more in the following blog post:

http://coreos.com/blog/Jumpers-and-the-software-defined-localhost/

Docker will soon allow to start a container sharing the network namespace of another container; it will help with those scenarios (and in the short term, it will allow to do what you suggest very easily).

Comment: "Software defined localhost". I like that.

Answer (score 0):

Project Atomic is also following this approach:

http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/inter-container-networking/

> Geard uses iptables to enable containers to connect to each other. Network namespaces allows adding iptables rules to the network namespace of a container. The basic idea is to make remote endpoints appear as if they were local to a container. For example the database container could be made to appear to be running locally inside the application container.